# Windows 10 (in a VM) forces time sync/update with setting disabled

Tags: windows-10, time, ntp, clock

I have Windows 10 in a VM to run some tests, some of which require me simulating a different or "wrong" time.  However Windows 10 seems to force the clock to the current time despite the **Set time automatically** and **Set time zone automatically** options being *disabled*.  I've even disabled the networking and it *still* forces the current time.

How do I actually get Windows 10 just let me set the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was actually VirtualBox forcing host/guest time synchronization.  I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041213/how-to-disable-virtualbox-time-sync-from-within-the-guest-at-runtime

`VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1`

Comment: does not work with VirtualBox 7.0.6